# java enums - cannot convert from MyClass.Result to int

Tags: java, enums, tostring, value-of

I have issues storing an enum value and then querying it via the `toString()` method. I require to handcode the numbers. How do I safely override my `toString()` ?

```
public enum Result {
        SUCCESS(0),
        INVALID_UPLOAD_KEY(-20),
        UPLOAD_KEY_NOT_FOUND(-80);

        private final int value;  //do I need this?

        private Result(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static Result fromInt(final int n) {
            for (final Result result : values()) {
                if (result.getValue() == n) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        public int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public String toString() {
            switch (this.value) {
                case UPLOAD_KEY_NOT_FOUND: //Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass.Result to int
                    return "Upload Key not found";
                case INVALID_UPLOAD_KEY: //Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass.Result to int
                    return "Invalid Upload Key";
                case SUCCESS: //Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass.Result to int
                    return "Success";
                default:
                    return "No result code associated with: " + this.value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Eclipse complains the `toString` method

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass.Result to int
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with generics? Where do you believe generics comes into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching on `enum` values, you can use the `enum` itself in the switch statement.  There is no need to look at your own custom value.  You can try:

```
switch (this) {
   case UPLOAD_KEY_NOT_FOUND:
       return "Upload Key not found";
   case INVALID_UPLOAD_KEY:
       return "Invalid Upload Key";
   case SUCCESS:
       return "Success";
   default:
       return "No result code associated with: " + this.value;
 }
```

Comment: For your `toString` method, the numbers you have (0, -20, -80) aren't necessary.  They appear to be necessary only in your `fromInt` method, for converting from an `int` to your `Result` type.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there a way to tell? I'm using someone else's code.

Comment: Do you need those specific numbers?  The `ordinal()` method will return Java's own internal numbers, but you don't control what numbers they are.

Comment: OK, it do appears that I need the numbers. The fromInt() was referenced elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained why your switch statement is failing - and unless you *need* the numbers for some other reason, you can get rid of them. But you don't need the switch statement at all - just make the *message* an instance variable:

```
public enum Result {
    SUCCESS("Success"),
    INVALID_UPLOAD_KEY("Invalid Upload Key"),
    UPLOAD_KEY_NOT_FOUND("Upload Key not found");

    private final String message;

    private Result(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Of course if you still need the integer value for other reasons, it's fine to keep that as well.

I would be tempted *not* to override `toString()`, but to provide a `getMessage()` method instead, by the way.

Comment: One reason I can think of overriding the toString method would be for adding the enum to a combo box, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
switch (this.value) {
case UPLOAD_KEY_NOT_FOUND: 
  return "Upload Key not found";
case INVALID_UPLOAD_KEY:
  return "Invalid Upload Key";
case SUCCESS:
  return "Success";
default:
  return "No result code associated with: " + this.value;
}
```

Should be

```
switch (this) {
case UPLOAD_KEY_NOT_FOUND: 
  return "Upload Key not found";
case INVALID_UPLOAD_KEY:
  return "Invalid Upload Key";
case SUCCESS:
  return "Success";
default:
  return "No result code associated with: " + this.value;
}
```

You are using the `enum` type in your case statements. You still need to numerical values you are assigning if need to use `fromInt(int)`.

Comment: Can I use ordinal() instead to get the numbers assigned internally by the VM?

Comment: Yes, but they'll be sequential and not negative.

Answer (score 0):

switch expects always constant values (an int or constant string).

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

In your case you should do something like this:

```
switch (this) {
    case -80: 
        return "Upload Key not found";
    case -20:
        return "Invalid Upload Key";
    case 0:
        return "Success";
    default:
        return "No result code associated with: " + this.value;
}
```

Or do not use the switch statement and try something like this:

```
return WordUtils.capitilize(this.getName().replace("_"))
```

Where WordUtils is this [library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html).

Comment: Actually switch also takes enums, but the case have to be the enum values. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: thanks, did not know that, then i guess the solutions at the top are right @Nederealm